# Using variable in stead of a hard coded string does not work in require()

Tags: react-native

I have tried to use

```
 const myPath = './TpsComponent2';
 const ms = require(myPath);
```

This does not work. However when I try,

```
 const ms = require('./TpsComponent2');
```

It works !

What am I missing ? I want to pass the path as a variable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native application is Javascript application (optionally with native code). Before it is run on device, it is bundled - ES6 is transpiled to ES5, assets are bundled as well.

This happens prior to running app. Thus, all `require`s must be known ahead of compilation time. You cannot require component (or anything else) in such way in RN app.

In pure node environment this is no problem.